# Intellij 12 and websphere liberty 8.5 next beta - Application server libraries not found

Tags: intellij-idea, websphere, websphere-liberty

I installed the latest WebSphere liberty profile to the Mac:

```
wlp-developers-runtime-8.5.next.beta.jar
```

WebSphere version is shown as `8.5.next.beta` in Intellij.

In Intellij 12 I try to add this WebSphere Application Server and I get:

> Cannot Save Settings: Application server libraries not found

If I look on the filesystem it seems that the location of:

- `com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsp.2.2_1.0.0.0.jar`
- `com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.0_1.0.0.jar`

has changes from `/dev/spec` to `/dev/api/spec`

I am not sure if this is the root cause, but Intellij seems to add these to the classpath in the previous version.  Is there a way to get intellij up and running e.g. can I change the location where it looks for the libs?

Comment: You should start with a [feature request to support it](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).

Comment: done - http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been officially fixed in Intelli 12.1.2 and newer.  The [release notes](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IntelliJ+IDEA+12.1.2+Release+Notes) and [original ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103787) have further details.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. There are two ways.

Either unpack wlp 8.5 into the folder where you want to have wlp 8.5.next. Once unpacked, point IntelliJ to that folder and it will detect it. Once detected, just remove the wlp folder and unpack the 8.5.next in the same. Once done, correct the library paths.

Or; Open IntelliJ's other.xml-file (it's usually in ~/.IntelliJIDEA12/config/options/other.xml) and modify as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application>
  <!-- other stuff -->
  <component name="AppserversManager">
    <LibraryTable>
      <library name="WebSphere 8.5.Next.Beta">
        <CLASSES>
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.annotation.1.1_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.cdi.1.0_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.ejb.3.1_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.el.2.2_1.0.1.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.interceptor.1.1_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxb.2.2_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxrs.1.1_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jaxws.2.2_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jms.1.1_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsf.2.0_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsf.tld.2.0_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsp.2.2_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jsp.tld.2.2_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.jstl.1.2_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.persistence.2.0_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.servlet.3.0_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.transaction.1.1_1.0.0.jar!/" />
          <root url="jar:///opt/wlp/dev/api/spec/com.ibm.ws.javaee.validation.1.0_1.0.0.jar!/" />
        </CLASSES>
        <JAVADOC />
        <SOURCES />
      </library>
    </LibraryTable>
    <ServerDK NAME="WebSphere 8.5.Next.Beta">
      <option name="SOURCE_INTEGRATION_NAME" value="WebSphere Server" />
      <DATA>
        <state>
          <option name="home" value="/opt/wlp" />
          <option name="version" value="8.5.next.beta" />
        </state>
      </DATA>
    </ServerDK>
  </component>
  <!-- rest -->
</application>
```